# How to know whether Android is connected to WiFi or ethernet?

Tags: android, wifi, ethernet

How to know whether I'm connected to WiFi or ethernet in Android?
In Android OS this is notified for thess icons
[image]

Does it exist a way to know it programmatically?

Comment: I would like to know this as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everybody

Just for avoid Exceptions (no network case). I share my tested code.

```
private Boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

public Boolean isWifiConnected(){
    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        ConnectivityManager cm 
        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }
    return false;
}

public Boolean isEthernetConnected(){
    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        ConnectivityManager cm 
        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().
            getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

And then you use:

```
cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET
```

or:

```
cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
```

to check whether it is on Wifi or Ethernet.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 5):

Is this enough?

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo Wifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if (Wifi.isConnected()) { return true; }
```

Also, to get wifi details:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
return wifiInfo.getSSID()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

You can find how to use it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)